# How to calculate the integral $\int\frac{e^{ixy}}{w^2-x^2}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis

How to calculate the integral$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{ixy}}{w^2-x^2}dx$$

where w,y are constants.

I tried to separate them as

$$\frac{1}{2w}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(\frac{e^{ixy}}{w+x}+\frac{e^{ixy}}{w-x})dx$$but I'm not sure this is a correct way.

Comment: Assuming that the integral is interpreted in Cauchy principal-value sense, the answer is $$ i\pi \left( \underset{z=-w}{\mathrm{Res}}\,\frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2-z^2} + \underset{z=w}{\mathrm{Res}}\,\frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2-z^2} \right) = \frac{\pi \sin(wy)}{w}. $$

Comment: If "x,w are constants" why are you integrating with respect to $x$?

Comment: For $Re(w) > 0$ then $\frac{1}{w^2+x^2}$ is the FT of $e^{-w |t|}$. Then the case $Re(w)=  0$ (integral interpreted in principal value) is obtained with the mean value of the FT of $e^{-(w+\epsilon)|t|}$ and $e^{-(-w+\epsilon)|t|}$

Comment: @SangchulLee thx, but why it's $\pi i$ not $2\pi i$ when you use Residue theorem?

Comment: That is essentially because we only wind the poles half-times.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following contour, where $\Gamma_R$ is a simicircular arc of the radius $R$ and $\gamma_{\pm,\epsilon}$ are semicircular arcs of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\pm w$, respectively.

$\hspace{5em}$ [image: Contour]

If we call this contour by $C$, then the Cauchy integration formula tells that

$$ \int_{C} \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z = 0. $$

Now note that

- $\displaystyle \left| \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z \right|
  \leq \frac{R}{R^2 - w^2} \xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{} 0 $,
- $\displaystyle \int_{\gamma_{\pm,\epsilon}} \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} \, \mathrm{d}z
  \xrightarrow[\epsilon\to 0^+]{} -i\pi \, \underset{z=\pm w}{\mathrm{Res}} \, \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} $.

So, letting $R \to \infty$ and $\epsilon \to 0^+$, we have

$$ \operatorname{PV}\!\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{iyx}}{w^2 - x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x - i\pi \left( \underset{z=- w}{\mathrm{Res}} \, \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} + \underset{z=w}{\mathrm{Res}} \, \frac{e^{iyz}}{w^2 - z^2} \right) = 0. $$

Comment: Thx, if I separate them as $\frac{e^{ixy}}{w+x}+\frac{e^{ixy}}{w-x}$, can I use $2\pi i$?

Comment: @Kinder, Not quite. Essentially this appears because we are  considering Cauchy principal value, not because of some special property of the integrand.

Comment: I'm confused which one I'm supposed to use $\pi i$ or $2\pi i$ compared with [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). I thought the arc integral is zero, is the whole contour integral also zero?

Comment: @Kinder, If you integrate a holomorphic function $f$ along a closed contour that winds the point $z_0$ counter-clockwise $n$ times, then there is $$2n\pi i \times [\text{residue of }f\text{ at }z_0]$$ contribution. If one opens up the proof, one can see that this comes from the limit $$\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_{0}^{2n\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})\,\mathrm{d}(e^{i\theta})=2n\pi i \times \text{[residue]}.$$ Similarly, in my computation, we end up with computing integral of the form $$\lim_{r\to0^+}\int_{0}^{\pi}f(z_0+re^{i\theta})\,\mathrm{d}(e^{i\theta}).$$

Comment: It is like the winding number around the point $z_0$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thx, but what if $z$ is complex? Then the singularity can be inside the winding instead of being in the edge. Shall I use $2\pi i$?

Comment: @Kinder, I guess you are referring to $w$. Anyway, if you are using a counter-clockwise oriented simple closed curve, then every point which is encompassed by the curve has winding number $1$, and so, you will use $2\pi i$.